# grep of output a previous grep

Tags: text-processing, grep

Is it possible to use the multi-line output of a `grep` run of one file as patterns for use with a subsequent second `grep` run on another file?

Example:

- content of `file1.txt`

  ```
  2 blue
  1 red 
  1 green
  2 black
  2 orange
  ```
- content of `file2.txt`

  ```
  2 blue triangle
  2 blue circle
  3 blue triangle
  2 red triangle
  3 green circle
  4 red square
  2 orange circle
  2 brown circle
  ```
- Result of first `grep`:

  ```shellsession
  $ grep 2 file1.txt 

  2 blue 
  2 black
  2 orange
  ```

Now, I am looking for a command that implements something like

```shell
grep <PREVIOUS OUTPUT> file2.txt
```

that would find all lines in `file2.txt` that start with one of the lines produced by the `grep` run on `file1.txt`, so the desired result is:

```
2 blue triangle
2 blue circle
2 orange circle
```

Comment: It strongly depends, so we would need more information to propose a definite solution. It seems you are working with table-based data. So, are the separators guaranteed to be always "one space"? Can the pattern `2 blue` appear anywhere else in `file2.txt` "by chance" (as in `4 red square and 2 blue triangles`), i.e. do you need full RegEx search for matching the lines in `file2.txt` against the output of the first `grep`? Are other standard text-processing tools also acceptable, or does it need to be `grep`?

Comment: If you have found a solution yourself, please don't edit your question to include it. Instead, add you own answer (as you already did).

Comment: It's not clear if you want a regexp or string comparison (your example only contains literal chars but we don't know if that's an oversight), nor if you want a partial match or full match, e.g. should `grep 2` on the first grep match `21 red` or `12 green` from the first file? should `2 blue` from file1 match `2 blueish-green` from file 2.

Comment: `grep -E "$(grep 2 file1.txt| awk '{ORS="|"; print}'| head -c-1)" file2.txt`

Comment: Are you willing to use `sed`, `awk`, `perl`, etc.?

Answer (score 15):

**This is the answer to the *literal* question.** For an answer that is likely better to solve the task, see the `awk` solution in the "Notes" below.

Assuming that the patterns found in `file1.txt` can only ever occur at the beginning of lines in `file2.txt`, you can use the `-f` flag to read multiple search patterns from a file rather than stating them as RegExes on the command-line. The file would then need to be connected to the output of your first `grep` run.

One way to do this is [process substitution](https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/process-sub.html):

```bash
grep -F -w -f <(grep -w 2 file1.txt) file2.txt
```

- The `<( ... )` construct makes the output of the command enclosed in parentheses available as if it were a file.
- The `-F` flag disables full RegEx search and is for safety and in case the output of the first `grep` run can contain characters with special meaning in the context of RegExes. It also speeds up the matching as literal string comparison is faster then RegEx matching.
- The `-w` flag ensures that no partial matches find their way into the results. This is particularly advisable for the first `grep` run in case the first column of `file1.txt` can contain multi-digit numbers such as `12`.

**Update**

As noted by @Stéphane Chazelas, the `-f` option accepts the often (but not always) implemented value of `-` to refer to the program's `stdin`, so you can also write this as

```bash
grep -w 2 file1.txt | grep -F -w -f - file2.txt
```

with the more easily recognized pipe-method to read from the output of another command.

---

**Note**

1. This assumes the pattern `number color` can only occur as the first two columns of `file2.txt`. If it can also occur later on the line, as in

   ```
   4 red square and 2 blue triangle
   ```

   such a line would be misidentified as also matching.
2. For working with tabulated data (as seems to be the case here), `awk` is usually a better-suited tool. Your task could be achieved by the following `awk` program:

   ```shell
   awk -v num="2" 'NR==FNR{if ($1==num){col[$2]}; next} ($1==num) && ($2 in col)' file1.txt file2.txt
   ```

   This will process both files. The search key is specified via an `awk` variable `num`.

   While processing the first file (where `NR`, the global line counter, is equal to `FNR`, the per-file line counter), it registers the color in the second column *in the indices of an array* `col` (hence no actual assignment to `col[$2]`) if the number in the first column matches. It then skips execution to the next line.

   When processing the second file, it checks if the first column matches the `num` variable, and if the second column is found among the indices of the array `col`. If so, the line is printed.

Answer (score 0):

Solved:

```shellsession
$ grep 2 file1.txt | xargs -I{} grep {} file2.txt

2 blue triangle
2 blue circle
2 orange circle
```

Comment: Note that `xargs` will choke on quotes or backslash characters and remove leading blanks. `grep` will also choke on strings starting with `-` (you'd need `--` or `-e`) and will treat them as regexp (you may want a `-F`). So `grep 2 file1.txt | xargs -d '\n' -I {} grep -Fe {} file2.txt` (assuming GNU `xargs`), though that'd still be quite inefficient as it runs on `grep` per matching line of `file1.txt`, each reading `file2.txt` in full.